# To ﬁlter out its input in lowercase character

Tags: unix, grep

Given an input file,I need to ﬁlter out its input in lowercase character.
I tried using:

```
cat filename | tr -s "[a-z][A-Z][0-9][:space:]" "[a-z]"
```

Comment: `tr -cd 'a-z' < filename`?

Comment: It's not clear from your question and your example what it is you want to do. Please give us a couple of example input filenames and the expected output filenames.

Comment: ... I possibly misunderstood even that. It's not filenames you want to convert, it's the *contents* of the files. Even so, some example lines of text would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

To transliterate all uppercase characters in a file to lowercase on a Unix system, use the `tr` utility like this:

```
$ tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' <inputfile >outputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

1) pls provide more details about problem

also look at

```
tr -s "[a-z][A-Z][0-9][:space:]" "[a-z]"
```

because it will lead you to disaster

*) [a-z] is wrong if u want get only-lower, correct is a-z 
*) amount of characters in sets is not equal -> it will repeat last character from set2 so your set2="[abcde...xyz]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]]..."